# custom ViewPager return touch coordinates to original reference frame for any child views

Tags: android, android-viewpager

### Solved

The goal I wanted to achieve is make the `ViewPager` to be more easier to scroll. I have solved it the by editing the original `ViewPager` source code instead of extending like below.

---

How can i return touch coordinates to original reference frame for any child views?Here is the `ViewPager` java file i always return y = 0 to make it scroll whenever x change just like the launcher's home screen.
My qusetion is that i need to return the real touch motion to the child views of the `ViewPager`

```
    public class myViewPager extends ViewPager
    {
        public myViewPager(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public myViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        /**
        * always return y = 0 to make it scroll whenever x change
        */
        private MotionEvent changeY(MotionEvent ev) {
            ev.setLocation(ev.getX(), 0);
            return ev;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
            // how to return touch coordinates to original reference frame for any child views ?
            return ???;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(changeY(ev));
        }

    }
```

Comment: can you describe your question more detailed?

Comment: how about change it before calling ```super.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)```

Answer (score 0):

How about changing it in dispatchTouchEvent? Like this:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(changeY(ev));
}
```

I was not very clean your problem, hope this can help you.

Comment: I want to achieve the viewpager like the google now launcher , that no matter what the y axis is , the scroll page action still occurs .